# Is it possible to write class template that works for all integral types?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

as you know template parameters may be types or integral values, 
so for example you can have

```
template<typename T, size_t BufferSize>
small_vector {
//...
```

Problem I have is that I want to write template that would work on different integral types.

So something like this:

```
constexpr short sa=1, sb=2, sc=3;
my_template_class1<sa,sb,sc>;
constexpr int ia=1, ib=2, ic=3;
my_template_class2<ia,ib,ic>;
```

In other words I know template type parameter can be int, what I want is to have a template that will work with integer template parameters for all integer types.
Note that I can not just do all the computations in int64 since it would not work for uint64.

Comment: have you tried `template <class T, T val>`?

Comment: C++17 will allow you to have `template<auto>`

Comment: W.F. I ended up using that, I wish it could deduce type of 'a', 'b', 'c' so i do  not need to write char, 'a', 'b', 'c' but I guess that is impossible. Feel free to make your comment into A and I will accept.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're interested in a template which will only work for integral types.  What you're looking for is `std::enable_if`.  By using this, a template will throw a compile error if you try to use anything but an integral type to create it.  It will also work for any and all integral types.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// 1. the return type (bool) is only valid if T is an integral type:
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value,bool>::type
  is_odd (T i) {return bool(i%2);}

// 2. the second template argument is only valid if T is an integral type:
template < class T,
           class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
bool is_even (T i) {return !bool(i%2);}

int main() {

  short int i = 1;    // code does not compile if type of i is not integral

  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "i is odd: " << is_odd(i) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "i is even: " << is_even(i) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As commented in another answer, I do not want to limit T to integer types, I want to enable integral template parameters without explicitly saying size_t, int,...

Answer (score -2):

Usually you achieve this by adding an extra "enabling" template parameter:

```
// the partial specialization of A is enabled via a template parameter
template<class T, typename BufferSize, class Enable = void>
class small_vector {}; // primary template, not used

template<class T, typename BufferSize>
class small_vector<class T, typename BufferSize, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<BufferSize>::value>::type> {
}; // specialization for various int types
```

Having said that, I would suggest not to put much efforts in various BufferSize implementations. They are likely to be used in compile-time only consume no memory or CPU.

Comment: problem here is that BufferSize here is int/size_t/short... but it can not be 5, 66, 11 and that is what I want.

Comment: Then you have to define a meta-programming functor which would "enable" all good values and disable all bad values. The library boost::mpl has a lot to offer. Your custom enabler will in fact be a template class and you will use it in the code above instead of the `enable_if<is_integral...>`